# jQuery to auto-scroll with skrollr on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, parallax, skrollr

I've made a parallax website for iOS using [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).  I'd like to programmatically scroll down to a point on the page.  I've used jquery scrolling plugins, and they work on desktop, but not mobile.  How can I simulate a swipeup or somehow simulate the scrolling to another point with jQuery?  Thanks!

EDIT: the reason this doesn't work is that on mobile, skrollr doesn't actually scroll due to iOS stopping animation during scroll.  Instead it listens for touch events and moves the elements.  That's why a scrollTo plugin won't work.  (Source: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#mobile-support)

Answer (score 7):

Actually I just realize that the skrollr API has this built in!

I can just call `skrollr.animateTo(400)` with skrollr being the variable that was used to initiate skrollr.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a FYI.

Pros and cons I found when implementing an auto scroll function for mobile with skrollr is this:

I used two libraries for touch events[jQuery Mobile, hammer.js]
I ended up sticking with hammer because I liked the documentation better.

The way I used it on an ipad was simple. I made it if you tap and hold on the right screen, it would auto scroll down until you let go. Vice versa on the left.

My problem is that it would fail to read the release event and keep scrolling and the user had no way to stop it.

After messing around with it for a bit I decided to change it up. What I did was place two buttons the user could tap on and it would auto scroll to the next section of my whole skrollr animation.

Here is an example of my code I wrote.

```
var ai = 0;
var positionArray = [0, 1244,3194,15468]
$(function () {
var rightArrow = document.getElementById('right-arrow')
var mcRight = new Hammer(rightArrow);
mcRight.on("tap", function (ev) {
    ai++
    s.animateTo(positionArray[ai])
    //alert(s.getScrollTop())
});


var leftArrow = document.getElementById('left-arrow')
var mcLeft = new Hammer(leftArrow);
mcLeft.on("tap", function (ev) {
    ai--
    s.animateTo(positionArray[ai])

});

})
```

Hope this helps. I wanted it my original way with tap & hold but both plugins had issues reading the taphold release event with the scrolling.

Another issue but super easy to fix by looking at the documentation is no matter how long the length of the section of your animation is, it will take 1 second to get there. Its nice if it is a small section but if you have a long one it scrub through it very fast.